# How to use CMake to find and link to a library using install-export and find_package?

Tags: cmake

You have a CMake-enabled library project. You need to use it in another library or executable. How to use CMake to find and link to the library? You may have the following preferences:

- write the least possible amount of boiler-plate code
- decouple the internal details of the linked library from the consuming target

Ideally, the usage of the library should look like this:

```
add_executable(myexe ...)
target_link_libraries(myexe mylib::mylib)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake link to external library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library)

Answer (score 55):

Let me demonstrate a possible solution on a concrete example:

## The `myapp` project

We have an executable target `myapp`. We're linking it with `mylib`, which is built in its own build tree. In the `CMakeLists.txt` of `myapp` we find and specify `mylib` as a dependency of `myexe`:

```
find_package(mylib REQUIRED)
...
add_executable(myexe ...)
target_link_libraries(myexe mylib::mylib)
```

Let's see how to set up `mylib` and the build of `myexe` to make this work.

## The `mylib` project

The directory layout of `mylib`:

```
mylib
- CMakeLists.txt
- mylib.c
+ include
  - mylib.h # single public header
```

In the `CMakeLists.txt` of `mylib` we need to create the target and specify its source files:

```
add_library(mylib mylib.c include/mylib.h)
```

The public header `mylib.h` will be included as `#include "mylib.h"` both by `mylib` and the clients of `mylib`:

- `mylib` itself and other targets built in `mylib`'s CMake project (for example tests) need to find `include/mylib.h` from the `mylib` source tree
- clients of `mylib` built in their own projects (like `myexe`) need to find `include/mylib.h` at its installed location

CMake allows us to specify both include paths for `mylib`:

```
target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)
```

We're using the `PUBLIC` option here since this header is needed on the public interface of `mylib`. Use `PRIVATE` for include paths internal to `mylib`.

The `INSTALL_INTERFACE` specifies a path relative to the install root, that is, `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`. To actually install the public header:

```
    set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER  include/mylib.h")
```

We also need to install the library itself and the so-called config-module and related files. The config-module is the file which will be used by consuming projects, like `myapp` to find `mylib` and get all the parameters needed to link with it. It is similar to the **pkg-config**'s `.pc` files.

We need two, related `install` commands. The first one:

```
install(TARGETS mylib
    EXPORT mylib-targets
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

The list of destinations needed to cover all the standard install locations of static libraries, `dll`'s and `so`'s. If you're sure your library will be built exclusively as a static lib, a single `DESTINATION lib` would make it.

The interesting part is the `EXPORT` option. It assigns the list of targets (currently, it's only `mylib`) to the identifier `mylib-targets`. This identifier will be used in the next command to generate and install some special files which make `find_package(mylib)` work in the consuming projects:

```
install(EXPORT mylib-targets
    NAMESPACE mylib::
    FILE mylib-config.cmake
    DESTINATION lib/cmake/mylib)
```

This command generates multiple files:

- one file for each build configuration (Debug, Release, etc..) which describes the library file and configuration-dependent parameters
- a file which describes the configuration-agnostic parameters and also includes all the config-dependent files. Since this file can also be used as a config-module on its own we simply rename it as `mylib-config.cmake`

The files will be installed into `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/cmake/mylib` which is one of the many standard locations the `find_package(mylib)` command will search for `mylib-config.cmake`.

## Building `mylib`

We need to specify an install location in the variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$PWD/../out ../mylib
```

and build and install the library:

```
cmake --build . --target install
```

## Building `myexe`

`myexe` needs to know where to look for `mylib`. The variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` can be a list of paths. We need to specify the previous install location:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$PWD/../out ../myexe
cmake --build .
```

## A note on building multiple configurations

Usually we need to build multiple configurations (`Debug`, `Release`). A critical issue is to specify configuration-dependent filenames or install locations. For example, you can set the default value of the `DEBUG_POSTFIX` property for the library project:

```
set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX d)
```

The debug version of the `mylib` library file will be named `libmylibd.lib` (or `mylibd.lib` on Windows). The generated `EXPORT` files will contain the modified filenames.

If you're using makefile-style CMake generators you can control the build configuration by setting the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$PWD/../out ../mylib
cmake --build . --target install
```

You may need seperate build directories for each configuration or you can re-use the same build dir. In that case, to play it safe it's best to explicitly clean before build:

```
cmake --build . --target install --clean-first
```

If you're using a multiconfig IDE generator, like `Xcode` or `Visual Studio`, you need to specify the configuration in build time:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$PWD/../out ../mylib
cmake --build . --target install --config Release
```

## References

You can clone and build [this repository](https://github.com/tamaskenez/stackoverflow-cmake-find-link-example) which contains the `mylib` and `myexe` projects (tested on Windows and Linux).

Check out the [CMake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3). The most important related commands are:

- [add_library](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/add_library.html)
- [target_link_libraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_link_libraries.html)
- [find_package](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/find_package.html)
- [install](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/install.html)
- [target_include_directories](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_include_directories.html)
- [target_compile_definitions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_compile_definitions.html)

and two detailed articles:

- [Build System](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html)
- [Packages](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake-packages.7.html)