# cmake_configuration_types and 3rd party libraries

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to create a custom `cmake_configuration_type` using the method as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546278/where-to-set-cmake-configuration-types-in-a-project-with-subprojects)
The issue I am facing is the correct linking of 3rd party libraries. E.g., when I create a custom configuration the executable is not linking correctly to third party libraries for the Final configuration. Some libraries linked to are in release mode and others in debug. Would anybody point me to whether CMake gives a way to resolve this issue ?

Here is the code as requested :
CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(DisplayImage)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake)

# Add configurations
include(SetupConfiguration)

# if (WIN32)
#   # Restrict the generated configuration to be what we configured above.
#   # No point creating project files for build types that will not compile.
#   # Note: it's set to FORCE so that both CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE and CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES match up.
#   set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} CACHE STRING "Build configurations to generate." FORCE)
#   mark_as_advanced(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
# endif()
message("Generated with config types: ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES}")

######################################################################
# Choose C++ standard. Currently 11, as we try to support VS2013.
######################################################################
set(mp_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS 0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD ${mp_CXX_STANDARD})
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

######################################################################
# Add Optional Requirements
######################################################################
if(WIN32)
  set(_library_sub_dir "bin")
else()
  set(_library_sub_dir "lib")
endif()

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

add_executable(DisplayImage main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS})
if (CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES MATCHES Release)
  set_property(TARGET DisplayImage PROPERTY MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Release>:Release>")
  set_target_properties(DisplayImage PROPERTIES RELEASE_POSTFIX "R")
elseif(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES MATCHES Final)
  set_property(TARGET DisplayImage PROPERTY MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Release>:Release>")
  set_target_properties(DisplayImage PROPERTIES RELEASE_POSTFIX "F")
  target_compile_definitions(DisplayImage PUBLIC -DFINAL)
elseif(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES MATCHES Debug)
  set_property(TARGET DisplayImage PROPERTY MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug")
  set_target_properties(DisplayImage PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX "D")
endif()
```

The main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("usage: DisplayImage.out <Image_Path>\n");
        return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

    if ( !image.data )
    {
        printf("No image data \n");
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("Display Image", image);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

In the CMake folder in the project the following two files mpSetupMSVCRuntime.cmake

```
if(MSVC)
    set(variables
        CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG
        CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
        CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE
        CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG
        CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE
        CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
        )
  add_definitions(/bigobj)
  add_definitions(/MP)
endif()
```

and SetupConfiguration.cmake

```
if(NOT SET_UP_CONFIGURATIONS_DONE)
    set(SET_UP_CONFIGURATIONS_DONE TRUE)

    get_property(isMultiConfig GLOBAL PROPERTY GENERATOR_IS_MULTI_CONFIG)
    if(isMultiConfig)
        set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "Debug;Release;Final" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
    else()
        if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
            message("Defaulting to release build.")
            set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
        endif()
        set_property(CACHE CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE PROPERTY HELPTSTRING "Choose the type of build")
        #set the valid options for cmake-gui drop-down list
        set_property(CACHE CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE PROPERTY STRINGS "Debug;Release;Final")
    endif()
    # now set up the Final configuration
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_FINAL "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_FINAL "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_FINAL "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
    set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_FINAL "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
    set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_FINAL "${CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)

endif()
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you provide an example CMake file showing *how* your third party libraries are linked? In general, this is what CMake [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) are for.

Comment: Without an example of libraries you use it is difficult to say what is going wrong.

Comment: I would also like to add that this is just an example in the actual project there are several third-party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

So finally I was able to solve this with some changes to the CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(DisplayImage)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake)

# Add configurations
include(SetupConfiguration)

# if (WIN32)
#   # Restrict the generated configuration to be what we configured above.
#   # No point creating project files for build types that will not compile.
#   # Note: it's set to FORCE so that both CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE and CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES match up.
#   set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} CACHE STRING "Build configurations to generate." FORCE)
#   mark_as_advanced(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
# endif()
message("Generated with config types: ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES}")

######################################################################
# Choose C++ standard. Currently 11, as we try to support VS2013.
######################################################################
set(mp_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS 0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD ${mp_CXX_STANDARD})
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

######################################################################
# Add Optional Requirements
######################################################################
if(WIN32)
  set(_library_sub_dir "bin")
else()
  set(_library_sub_dir "lib")
endif()

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
foreach(_cvlib ${OpenCV_LIBS})
  set_target_properties(${_cvlib} PROPERTIES MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_FINAL "RELEASE")
endforeach()
add_executable(DisplayImage main.cpp)
if (CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES MATCHES Release)
  target_link_libraries(DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS})
  set_property(TARGET DisplayImage PROPERTY MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Release>:Release>")
  set_target_properties(DisplayImage PROPERTIES RELEASE_POSTFIX "R")
elseif(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES MATCHES Final)
  target_link_libraries(DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS})
  set_property(TARGET DisplayImage PROPERTY MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Final>:Final>")
  set_target_properties(DisplayImage PROPERTIES RELEASE_POSTFIX "F")
  add_definitions(-DFINAL)
elseif(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES MATCHES Debug)
  target_link_libraries(DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS})
  set_property(TARGET DisplayImage PROPERTY MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug")
  set_target_properties(DisplayImage PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX "D")
endif()
```

The key was to use the `MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_<CONFIG>` feature of CMake.