# CMake: what is the correct syntax for $<CONFIG:cfg_list> or $<IN_LIST:str,list>?

Tags: cmake, cmakelists-options, cmake-language

Using CMake version 3.20.1, I'm doing something that I consider to be relatively simple: verify that the value of `cfg` pass via `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=<cfg>` is a valid configuration.

Referencing the [CMake generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) docs, it appears that `$<CONFIG:cfgs>` is a specialized case of `$<IN_LIST:string,list>` where the string is `${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES}`.  The CMake runtime-error I'm getting reinforces this, as well as telling me that I'm missing something.

What I'm expecting to work is this:

```
    set( CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "Debug;Release" CACHE STRING "Build Configurations" FORCE )
    
    if( NOT $<CONFIG:${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES}> )
      # Handle_the_bad_value()
    endif()
```

when called from the command line as `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`, but I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:45 (if):
  if given arguments:

    "NOT" "\$<CONFIG:Debug" "Release>"

  Unknown arguments specified
```

Replacing

```
$<CONFIG:<cfg_list>
```

with either:

```
$<IN_LIST:${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE},${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES}>
```

or

```
$<IN_LIST:"Debug","Debug;Release">
```

gives me the following:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:43 (if):
  if given arguments:

    "NOT" "\$<IN_LIST:Debug,Debug" "Release>"

  Unknown arguments specified
```

I've played around with various changes to the original syntax before experimenting with `$<IN_LIST:str,list>`, but being that I cannot get the `IN_LIST` syntax to work, I feel there is something fundamental that I am getting wrong that I'm also failing to grasp from the documentation.

---

Subsequent experimentation, using:

```
    if( NOT ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} IN_LIST ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES} )
```

yields:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:43 (if):
  if given arguments:

    "NOT" "Debug" "IN_LIST" "Debug" "Release"

  Unknown arguments specified
```

So I tried brute force:

```
if( NOT ( "Debug" IN_LIST "Debug;Release" ) )
```

which evaluates, but incorrectly, because it does not find "Debug" in the list, so it enters the code within the if-statement.  Final try:

```
    if( NOT ( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE IN_LIST CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES ) )
```

**Does** work as expected.  Noted:  `NOT` should apply to an *expression* that is within parenthesis.  But it still doesn't help me understand the correct syntax for the `CONFIG` generator expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use *generator expressions* in `if` command, because generator expressions are expanded only at the end of configuration process, but `if` condition needs to be evaluated immediately.

Expression `$<IN_LIST:<$CONFIG>,${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES}>` is valid
in BOOL context of other generator expression. But it could be used only for produce another string, not for emit an error.

If you want to check correctness of the build type, specified by a user, following things should be taken into account:

1. On **multi-configuration** generators (like Visual Studio) a build type is given by `--config` option at build stage. CMake **automatically checks** such build type for match against `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES`, so there is no needs in manual checks.
2. On **single-configiration** generators (like Makefile) a build type is specified via `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable. So there is no needs in a generator expression to refer a build type.
3. Variable `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` should be specified **only** for multi-configuration generators. Setting it for single-configuration generators could confuse some scripts (e.g. `FindXXX.cmake`).

So, you could check a build type in the following way (based on the code in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31548693/3440745))

```
# Use custom variable for avoid setting CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES
# for single-configuration generators.
set(MY_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "Debug;Release")

# Check whether generator is single-configuration or multi-configuration
get_property(isMultiConfig GLOBAL PROPERTY GENERATOR_IS_MULTI_CONFIG)
if(isMultiConfig)
    # Multi-configuration generator
    # Set possible values. CMake automatically checks correctness.
    set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "${MY_CONFIGURATION_TYPES}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE) 
else()
    # Single-configuration generator
    if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
        # If not set, set the build type to default.
        message("Defaulting to release build.")
        set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
    else()
        # Check correctness of the build type entered by user
        # Note that the right operand for IN_LIST should be **variable**,
        # not just a list of values
        if (NOT (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE IN_LIST MY_CONFIGURATION_TYPES))
            message(FATAL_ERROR "Incorrect build type")
        endif()
    endif()
    set_property(CACHE CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE PROPERTY HELPSTRING "Choose the type of build")
    # set the suggested values for cmake-gui drop-down list
    # Note, that CMake allows a user to input other values.
    set_property(CACHE CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE PROPERTY STRINGS "${MY_CONFIGURATION_TYPES}")
endif()
```

Comment: I found a post yesterday suggesting what you've stated, but you've explained it much better.  So the correct answer is "you cannot get there from here."  Not what I wanted to hear, but I know to stop spinning my wheels.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using CMake consists of two stages:

- configure stage `cmake -S . -B _build` or `cd _build && cmake ..` etc.
- build stage `cmake --build _build` or `cd _build && make` etc.

Generator expressions `$<suff>` are expanded *when* building the project. They are *not* expanded inside CMake scripts. For CMake script, when configuring the project, it's just text.

To compare it in CMake, compare it in CMake. I guess:

```
if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE IN_LIST CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
```

Comment: I understand the two steps, and right now I'm hung up on just the first step.  `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is a CMake implicit variable, and the user can explicitly specify it at the command line, or they can just run with the default (which is an empty string, so if your CMake script cares, you need to specify a default).  IIRC, `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` is also an implicit CMake variable.

Comment: Och `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` it is? I didn't knew ;) Sorry.