# CMake nested libraries

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a Project in c++ where my `executable` depends on my `core library` and that library depends on another external library, `libtorrent` if it is of any relevance.

The problem is I can not figure out how to setup my CMakeLists.txt, I have been searching for days now, without avail.

The main idea is that the `core library` and the `executable` are on seperate git repositories, so the library is not a sub git module of the executable.

Preferably I would be able to use ExternalProject_Add to add the `core library` to the `executable` but when I do this, the `executable` complains that it does not know anything about `libtorrent` which again the core library uses. Adding the headers of `libtorrent` to the executable wasn't enough, I would also need to link the `executable` to `libtorrent`. But why would I compile the `core library` then anyway, since I just have to add all dependencies of the `core library` to the `executable` again.

If someone can point me in the right direction of how to setup a project that uses a core library that has other dependencies and an executable that uses the core library.

Comment: Standard approach is to use `find_package(libtorrent REQUIRED)` to compile your `core_lib` and `find_package(core_lib REQUIRED)` in `CMakeLists.txt` of your executable. Then your `core_lib` can either be installed in the system, or you can point CMake to look for it in your projects local directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, this is represented with targets and links between them.

Your setup could look like this:

```
#  core cmake file
find_package(LibtorrentRasterbar REQUIRED)

add_library(core_lib file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp ...)
target_link_libraries(core_lib PUBLIC LibtorrentRasterbar::torrent-rasterbar) # see below
```

```
# app cmake file

find_package(core_lib) # find it elsewhere

add_executable(app file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp ...)
target_link_libraries(exec PRIVATE core_lib::core_lib)
```

If core needs new libraries in it's headers, then you should add them to the dependencies of `core_lib`. Any public requirement is transitively propagated to users, like the `app` target.

The depedencies with external libraries or build tree is expressed using `find_library`. It can be a library installed in your root, installed in your user directory installed in a subdirectory of your project or simply the build tree of the library. In your case, finding the build tree is probably what you want.

Then since your `core_lib` library sits in another project, I suggest to go looking at how to export targets from a build tree or an installation, so `find_package(core_lib)` would work.

---

Unfortunately `Libtorrent` does not appear to support CMake properly, so the package `Libtorrent` won't be found and target `Libtorrent::torrent-rasterbar` won't be defined.

There are ways to work around by trying their `FindLibtorrentRasterbar.cmake`.

Looking at [their find module](https://github.com/steeve/libtorrent/blob/master/examples/cmake/FindLibtorrentRasterbar.cmake), it's clear it's not made with modern cmake in mind. You'll have to add these lines at the end if the file to support linking to their targets:

```
if(LibtorrentRasterbar_FOUND)
    set(LibtorrentRasterbar_LIBRARY_DEPS "${LibtorrentRasterbar_LIBRARIES}")
    list(REMOVE_ITEM LibtorrentRasterbar_LIBRARY_DEPS ${LibtorrentRasterbar_LIBRARY})

    if(LibtorrentRasterbar_USE_STATIC_LIBS)
        add_library(LibtorrentRasterbar::torrent-rasterbar STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
    else()
        add_library(LibtorrentRasterbar::torrent-rasterbar SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
    endif()

    set_target_properties(LibtorrentRasterbar::torrent-rasterbar PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${LibtorrentRasterbar_LIBRARY}
        INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES ${LibtorrentRasterbar_LIBRARY_DEPS}
        INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS ${LibtorrentRasterbar_DEFINITIONS}
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${LibtorrentRasterbar_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    )
endif()
```

---

One detail I didn't mention is that `find_package` won't try to find the packages of your dependency. To do that, create a custom config file that look like this:

```
# cmake/core_lib-config.cmake.in
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)

# this line is just like a find_package
# but made for transitivity
find_dependency(LibtorrentRasterbar)
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/core_lib-targets.cmake")
```

Then change your exportation to output into `core_lib-targets.cmake` instead of the usual config:

```
# this is the new config file with the add_dependency
configure_file(
    cmake/core_lib-config.cmake.in
    core_lib-config.cmake
    @ONLY
)

# the new config file will include this target file
install(EXPORT core_lib_targets
        NAMESPACE core_lib::
        FILE core_lib-targets.cmake
        DESTINATION lib/cmake/core_lib)

# export the current build tree
export(
    EXPORT core_lib_targets
    NAMESPACE core_lib::
    FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/core_lib-targets.cmake"
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I have been trying to use their FindLibtorrentRasterbar.cmake file, however, no matter how I install libtorrent LibtorrentRasterbar remains NOT_FOUND. How could I go around this problem?

Comment: Their `FindLibtorrentRasterbar.cmake` is using package config files to get the path and interface requirement of their library. Unfortunately, I'm not really familiar with package config.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway, I think with the dependencies the main problem should be fixed. I will try it out as soon as I can

Comment: So I have exported my core_lib which btw correctly found libtorrent, and it creates an exports.cmake file in the cmake-build-debug folder (I am using CLion) but I do not understand how my app should find this project now?

Comment: @J.Paravicini I have found an [excellent answer about exporting libraries here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31537603/2104697). Also, don't fear looking at how other projects has done it. For example, [nlohmann_json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/develop/CMakeLists.txt#L102) is doing a pretty good job with it's cmake support.

Comment: @J.Paravicini Also, for cmake to find your other project, you'll have to set the prefix path to the build directory of your library: `cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/to/core/build ..` although this is explained in the answer I linked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196971/discussion-between-j-paravicini-and-guillaume-racicot).