# Cannot find API header file for shared library with cmake

Tags: c, cmake, shared-libraries

I am building a shared library in one project and using it in another.  They share a prefix, but I'm not building them together (e.g., `<prefix>/mylib` and `<prefix>/myproject`).  Both `mylib` and `myproject` have `src` and `include` directories.

The `CMakeList.txt` for the shared library:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(mylib)

add_library(mylib SHARED
            src/mylib.c
            )

target_include_directories(mylib PRIVATE include)

set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER include/mylib.h)

install(TARGETS
  mylib
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

This results in `mylib.so` being installed in `install/mylib/lib/mylib.so` and `mylib.h` being installed in `install/mylib/include/mylib.h`, which is what I intended.

I then want to build a project that uses `mylib`:

```
#include "mylib.h"

int main(void)
{
    // use some functions in mylib
}
```

The associated `CMakeList.txt` file for `main.c`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(myproject)

find_package(mylib REQUIRED)

add_executable(myproject src/main.c)
target_link_libraries(myproject mylib)

install(TARGETS
  myproject
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})
```

This produces:

```
main.c: fatal error: mylib.h: No such file or directory
#include "mylib.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~
```

If I change `CMakeList.txt` to include the following:

```
find_path(MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR mylib.h)
...
target_include_directories(myproject PUBLIC ${MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Then it finds the header, but not the library.  I get a linker error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmylib
```

If I change `CMakeList.txt` to include the following:

```
find_library(MYLIB_LIB mylib)
...
target_link_libraries(myproject ${MYLIB_LIB})
```

Then it builds.

I (think I) understand why finding the library and include files manually works, but that seems to be the wrong way to go about things...

`find_package(mylib)` does seem to find the `mylib` package (I can print cmake cache variables and `mylib_FOUND=1`), but doesn't find the library and header in such a way that they are built with `myproject`.

Comment: "`find_package(mylib)` does seem to find the `mylib` package" - It finds actually, otherwise CMake would emit an error message during the configuration. But it is **not clear** how do you define this package. It should be a script, either `mylibConfig.cmake` or `Findmylib.cmake` which is executed by `find_package(mylib)` call. CMake is able to generate `mylibConfig.cmake` for your `mylib` project. But your `CMakeLists.txt` for that project doesn't contain `EXPORT` keyword in `install(TARGETS)` call, it doesn't contain `install(EXPORT)` command.

Comment: You're right.  I needed to use EXPORT.  If you change this to an answer, I'll accept it.  Perhaps also point to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31537603/12519897), which I found immensely helpful after you got me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify include directories for both "build" and "install" variants in `target_include_directories` in your library project:

```
target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include> # build variant
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include> # install variant
)
```

BTW, such example is provided in documentation for [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/target_include_directories.html) command.

Additionally, you need to `EXPORT` the library during installation:

```
install(
  TARGETS mylib
  EXPORT mylib
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537602/how-to-use-cmake-to-find-and-link-to-a-library-using-install-export-and-find-pac/31537603#31537603) for a tutorial on exporting libraries with cmake.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't install my API header (`mylib.h`) in the install directory.  

Further, I was already using  

```set_target_properties(macaroons PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER include/macaroons.hpp)
```. 

Which *was* placing `mylib.h` in `<prefix>/install/mylib/include`.

Comment: Command `target_include_directories` does not handle public headers installation. It just defines include directory. You still need `install(TARGETS ... PUBLIC_HEADER)` command for installing header files.

Comment: Ok.  Perhaps I don't understand the scope or intended effect of your answer.  I already had a `target_include_directories` command, as well as a `set_target_properties` and `install` command, as shown in the OP.  Changing my `target_include_directories` command, as you suggested, didn't have any effect on either the installed location of my API header (`mylib.h`) nor the ability to find either the API header or the library file when building `myproject`.  Do I need to make changes to the `CMakeList.txt` file for `myproject` in addition to the change you suggested to the file for `mylib`?